# have you drawn any watches?

Tags: phrases

In the book *A Song of Ice and Fire* I came across this sentence, the meaning of which isn't clear to me:

> "Have you drawn any watches this past week, Will? Yes,m'lord."

What does this sentence mean and what is a watch?

Comment: What is the nature of the character?  Is he a thief?

Answer (score 8):

"To draw (something)" is to be chosen by lottery to perform a certain task, in this case night watch of the camp. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drawing_straws) for an example of what "drawing (something)" entails. Whether the marker for the lottery is a stone, stick, straw or some other token is irrelevant, what matters is that it is a "random" selection of a choice.

The typical process is:

1. All prospective choices for a task or decision are grouped. All choices in that group have an equal chance of being chosen.
2. Group members make a selection (a stick from the basket, a number from 1-10, etc).
3. According to some predetermined criteria, a choice is chosen based on their selection.

Of course, the "lots" system was occasionally used loosely in history and it's equally as feasible that "drawing watch" was nothing more than being told, "Hey, you're on watch tonight."

According to Greek mythology, Zeus, Hades, and Poseidon used an extended form of this principle, sortition, to choose who would rule what sphere.

To your second question, a "watch" is close observation and vigilance, and those that engage in such activity.

Enjoy the books!

Answer (score 7):

In this context to "draw a watch" is be be assigned guard duty.

Comment: ty for answer :-) helpful

Answer (score 2):

It means being assigned to guard duty.